# Create an empty OPENARRAY in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder, superobject

I'm using C++Builder with SuperObject JSON parser, and trying to construct an array.

```
_di_ISuperObject json = SO("{}");
json->O["data.names"] = SA(ARRAYOFCONST(("")));

for (int i=0; i < v.size(); ++i)
  json->A["data.names"]->S[i] = v[i];
```

Now, the code above does what I want - unless `v.size() == 0`. In that case, I get an array with a single 'empty' string in it.

This is because of the 'dummy' array creation using `ARRAYOFCONST((""))`.

What's the correct way to create an 'empty' `OPENARRAY` to pass to SuperObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `ARRAYOFCONST()` or `OPENARRAY()` to create a 0-element openarray.  Those macros require a minimum of 1 input value.

I am not familiar with SuperObject, but if `O[]` creates a new JSON array from existing values and `A[]` simply fills the array, you could try using the `SLICE()` macro to create and fill an openarray from `v` directly if `v` is a `std::vector<TVarRec>`:

```
if (!v.empty())
    json->O["data.names"] = SA( SLICE(&v[0], v.size()) );
```

If you really need a 0-element openarray if `v` is empty, try this:

```
if (v.empty())
    json->O["data.names"] = SA( NULL, -1 );
else
    json->O["data.names"] = SA( SLICE(&v[0], v.size()) );
```

If `v` does not contain `TVarRec` values then you can create a separate `std::vector<TVarRec>` first and then `SLICE()` that into SuperObject (just be careful because `TVarRec` does not perform reference counting on reference-counted data types, such as strings - *by design* - so make sure temporaries are not created when you assign the `TVarRec` values or else they will be leaked!):

```
if (v.empty())
    json->O["data.names"] = SA( NULL, -1 );
else
{
    std:vector<TVarRec> tmp(v.size());
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < v.size(); ++idx)
        tmp[idx] = v[idx];
    json->O["data.names"] = SA( SLICE(&tmp[0], tmp.size()) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `SA(NULL, -1)` did the trick for me, without the cast. `SLICE` fails though: My `std::vector` contains `UTF8String`s, so I was expecting that might work...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Obviously `SA()` is declared as taking an `array of const`, which expects `TVarRec` values, so `SLICE(v)` would only work for a vector of `TVarRec` values. A vector of `UTF8String` values would only work if `SA()` accepted an `array of UTF8String` instead. But that does go back to my comment of needing to create a separate array/vector of openarray-compatible values when calling `SA()` with a non-empty vector.